# Kali Linux 2.0 shortcut command property

Tags: kali-linux, chrome

**Kali Linux 2.0** released with awesome UI and performance.
Today I installed **Kali Linux 2.0** after installing updates I installed **Google Chrome**. Now The problem is that I cannot access chrome command property in Kali Linux 2.0 nor in the **Top Bar** nor in the **Dash to Dock** . The **Kali Dev team** have changed the simple gnome to **gnome 3.14**. 
In early versions of Kali we right click on an application in **Top bar** and select property. where we were changing command.

> https://abraoximenes.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/screenshot-from-2013-05-21-202349.png

I need this for chrome because I want to run google-chrome as **standard user** while logged in as **root**.
I have created a user for chrome using....

```
useradd -m chromeuser
```

Now whenever i want to run chrome as standard user while logged in as root I run.

```
gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome
```

I want to add this line to chrome property command .

***My question is is there any way to modify application shortcut property in Kali Linux 2.0 (Gnome 3.14.1) using CLI?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install the Gnome tools here the command to install

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

And then use this command it will create a launcher on desktop

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit /root/Desktop --create-new
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 2 options:

1. Edit the GNOME menu: In newer version of GNOME, the menu editor (i.e. Alacarte) was hidden, launch it by `alacarte`. Note that you shouldn't blame Kali's devs for this, because this is GNOME design and they repect that (and the GNOME Flashback you used to use got dropped a long time ago, you might want to try GNOME Classic instead).
2. Edit the launcher: Google Chrome launcher could be either one of these (I'm not using it so not sure which is the one):

`/opt/google/chrome/goole-chrome.desktop`

`/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

`/usr/local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

Open with your favorite text editor and change `google-chrome` to `gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome`